# Jquery conflicting and error says $(...).attr is not a function

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

I am using **jQuery-1.7.2 .js** in my view. When i use first js then the error don't come and i perform my task without no error but when i include my 2nd js then i face error  and error is  **$(...).attr is not a function**
here is code

this is view

```
     <a title="Minimize Chat Window" class="abc" id="minmax" href="#Minimize Chat Window" onclick="min_max(this);">
```

this is js

```
<script src="<?=base_url()?>js/libs/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" >

function min_max(i)
{
    var cls=$(i).attr('class');
    if(cls == 'abc')
    {
        $(i).removeClass('xyz');
    }
    else
    {
        $(i).addClass('xyz');
    }
}
```

but when i include my 2nd one js after or before first one then

```
var cls=$(i).attr('class');
```

gives error that **$(...).attr is not a function**

plz help me to find out my problem.I thought its jquery conflicting.  but i want to use both js in my view. thanks

Comment: What is in you 2nd js file?

Comment: what is 'i'? can you show us an example of the selector used for it?

Comment: what do you see in Firebug if you add a `console.log(i)` to your `min_max()` function? I'm pretty sure the root problem is that your selector is invalid, so you're trying to call `attr()` on a null object.

Comment: Tieson i find problem just i need to use jQuery instead $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use this line **var $ = jQuery.noConflict();** after your script tag start then u can use **$** instead **Jquery**

```
<script src="<?=base_url()?>js/libs/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" >

 var $ = jQuery.noConflict();

 function min_max(i)
 {
   var cls=$(i).attr('class');
   if(cls == 'abc')
   {
       $(i).removeClass('xyz');
   }
   else
   {
       $(i).addClass('xyz');
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To avoid that kind of problems use `jQuery`'s `noConflict()` function, and then change `$()` calls with `jQuery()` calls.

Have a look to the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/).

Answer (score 1):

To rule out a conflict change `var cls=$(i).attr('class');` for `var cls=jQuery(i).attr('class');`

See more about noConflict here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/